# Los módulos nuevos no se muestran en el menú con XavaPro

Tags: java, jpa, openxava

Cuando actualizo mi aplicación OpenXava a XavaPro, todos los módulos de mi aplicación están disponibles en XavaPro automáticamente. Por ejemplo, si tengo tres módulos, Cliente, Factura y Producto, estos módulos se muestran en el menú de la izquierda en XavaPro. Perfecto.

Sin embargo, si añado un nuevo módulo a mi aplicación, escribiendo una entidad JPA, de esta manera:

```
@Entity
public class Pedido {
  // ...
}
```

Mientras que en una aplicación OpenXava simple y llana Pedido se añadiría el menú de la izquierda, con XavaPro el módulo Pedido no se muestra en el menú:

[image: Nuevo módulo no se muestra en el menú]

El módulo no se muestra, incluso si lo declaro explícitamente en aplicacion.xml.

¿Cómo puedo mostrar los nuevos módulos en el menú con XavaPro?

Answer (score 1):

Al actualizar tu aplicación de OpenXava a XavaPro, XavaPro crea un nuevo rol llamado 'user' y le añade todos los módulos de tu aplicación. Después de ese momento, tienes que añadir explícitamente tus nuevos módulos al rol 'user' o a cualquier otro. Esto funciona de esta forma para evitar exponer módulos a usuarios no autorizados inadvertidamente, simplemente por desplegar en producción nuevo código.

Para añadir los nuevos módulos al menú de la izquierda, ve al módulo Roles (dentro de la carpeta Admin). Allí escoge el rol 'user'. Después, en el detalle, pulsa en Añadir in la lista de módulos, escoge el nuevo módulo, Pedido en este caso, y ya está:

[image: Añadir módulo a role user]

Después de eso tu usuario ya verá el módulo Pedido.